# How to check if an image file ftp is complete (via Nikon wireless image upload) with a php cron

Tags: php, image, ftp, cron, imagemagick

I have created a small app for a photographer that shoots live pictures during music events.

1. The images are sent from the Nikon camera to my ftp server.
2. The app checks (cron) wether in the specified folder there are new images
3. Then copies them to the "develop" folder, processes them with ImageMagick (resizing, filtering and watermarking)
4. Then moves them to the "send" folder and attaches them to an email that is sent to specified recipients.

The problem: i'd like to be able to check if the images are completely uploaded before processing them. The cron runs every 5 minutes and the photographer shoots continuously during a concert.

I have been checking here for similar questions but I didn't really find a solution. So, in case is a duplicated question, I apologise for that.

Thanks, s@ch@x

**UPDATE #1** - Here's the test I have made with Mark Setchell's suggestion:

```
`exec("convert -regard-warnings -size 1280x44.879451 xc:none -gravity center -pointsize 24 -font 'Times-Bold' -stroke black -strokewidth 1 -annotate 0 '©M.Setchell' -background none -shadow 100x3+0+0 +repage -stroke none -fill white -annotate 0 '©M.Setchell' roll/SUBSONICA.JPG +swap -gravity south -geometry +0-3 -composite send/SUBSONICA.JPG && rm roll/SUBSONICA.JPG");`
```

and

```
`exec("convert -size 1280x44.879451 xc:none -gravity center -pointsize 24 -font 'Times-Bold' -stroke black -strokewidth 1 -annotate 0 '©M.Setchell' -background none -shadow 100x3+0+0 +repage -stroke none -fill white -annotate 0 '©M.Setchell' roll/SUBSONICA.JPG -regard-warnings +swap -gravity south -geometry +0-3 -composite send/SUBSONICA.JPG && rm roll/SUBSONICA.JPG");`
```

Following vars come from php:
`-size 1280x44.879451` ( `$imageSize = getimagesize($developDir . $developFile);` )
`-annotate 0 '©M.Setchell'` ( `$watermark`)
`roll/SUBSONICA.JPG` (the input file: `$developDir . $developFile` in the `foreach` statement)
`send/SUBSONICA.JPG` (output file: `$sendDir . $developFile` in the `foreach` statement)

By testing, while uploading images manually via ftp, I got the email expected with 8 attachments, of which 4 where still partial images.

**UPDATE #2** - I added in the `exec` function an array for the output and a var for the return status of the executed command - as in @Mark Setchell's update below.

Then, with a simple `if ... else` statement, I could easily analyse the result:

- if (return status == **1**) the image file is not a valid and completed one, so we remove the image from the processed folder (the "send" folder in my app)
- else (return status == **0**) file is a valid & a complete image file: we remove the file from the ftp folder where the photographer sends the images directly from the Nikon camera (the "roll" folder in my app).

So, the correct and complete `exec` string, based on @Mark Setchell's answer, is:

```
`convert -regard-warnings -size 1024x40 xc:none -gravity center -pointsize 20 -font 'Times-Bold' -stroke black -strokewidth 1 -annotate 0 '©2016 Mark Setchell' -background none -shadow 100x3+0+0 +repage -stroke none -fill white -annotate 0 '©2016 Mark Setchell' roll/SUBSONICA_small.jpg +swap -gravity south -geometry +0-3 -composite send/SUBSONICA_small.jpg`
```

Here's the code snippet that worked perfectly:

```
exec("convert $im_cmd", $convert_output, $returned_var);
    if ($returned_var) {
        unlink($send_dir . "/" . $developFile);

    } else {
        unlink($develop_dir . "/" . $developFile);
    }
```

This solution works perfectly and after 10 tests it proved super-reliable: instead of checking the files via php, as the initial question asked, @Mark Setchell's approach - the use of the `-regard-warnings` option of the Imagemagick convert program [link](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#regard-warnings) – solved the problem.

Comment: PHP may not be the best approach in this case.  Are you wanting it to wait until all images are uploading before starting at all?  How would the server have any idea that the photographer decided not to take any more pictures?  Or do you just want to make sure individual files are completely uploaded before processing them?

Comment: What software transfers the inages from the Nikon to the FTP server? If that is under your control you can start upliading an image as `xyz.upload` and rename it as `xyz` when complete. Then on the server, you ignore files ending in `.upload`.

Comment: @Lotharyx I just want to make sure that individual files are completely uploaded before processing them. The script will run every 5 minutes as a cron job. Every time it runs it will check the "camera_roll" directory to see if there are images to process. In case it finds images, it passes them to another directory and processes them. So, it will run continuously. During a concert, when the photographer shoots and sends the best images to the server, the process will do its job. But i need to know if the file I am moving are still being transferred.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I don't know. It is not under my control. I have read here on some topic about this solution, and it would be perfect, but the software is embedded into the transmitter (http://cdn-10.nikon-cdn.com/pdf/manuals/wireless/WT-5_EN.pdf) and I didn't find any info about it. So, I wanted a kinda workaround, I guess.

Comment: One silly idea, your cron job could also `grep` the output of `lsof` to make sure the file isn't currently open before moving it.  Or maybe better, your FTP server might be able to perform an action when a file upload is complete; so the active transfer goes to a temporary location, then the server process itself moves the completed file into the right place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

Ok, we are close now! If you want to use PHP rather than the command-line, you need to get the return value from `exec()` do something dependent on that value. So, if you check [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php), you can see how to get the return value:

```
exec("convert -regard-warnings inputfile ... resize ... filter ... output/outputfile",array &$output, int &$return_var);
```

Then, if the `$return_var` is zero, you need to remove the input file because the command worked, and if it is non-zero, you need to remove the output file because it didn't.

**Original Answer**

You could let ImageMagick tell you if the file is incomplete. So, rather than copying the files blindly and *"en masse"* from the FTP directory, use Imagemagick `convert` to process them from there to the processed directory and only remove the ones that get processed successfully, leaving any others to be processed on the next cron invocation on the basis that they were incomplete. So, something like this:

```
cd FTPDirectory
for f in *.jpg; do
    convert -regard-warnings ... resize ... sharpen ... "%f" processed/"%f"
    # If successful, delete source file
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        rm "%f"
    fi
done
```

The `-regard-warnings` flag causes warnings to be treated as errors. So, if I don't use it, I get no error status when processing an incomplete file:

```
convert incomplete.jpg  processed.jpg
convert: Premature end of JPEG file `incomplete.jpg' @ warning/jpeg.c/JPEGWarningHandler/352.
convert: Corrupt JPEG data: premature end of data segment `incomplete.jpg' @ warning/jpeg.c/JPEGWarningHandler/352.

echo $?
0
```

Whereas if I do use it, I get a catchable error:

```
convert -regard-warnings incomplete.jpg  processed.jpg
convert: Premature end of JPEG file `incomplete.jpg' @ warning/jpeg.c/JPEGWarningHandler/352.
convert: Corrupt JPEG data: premature end of data segment `incomplete.jpg' @ warning/jpeg.c/JPEGWarningHandler/352.

echo $?
1
```

Comment: Sounds perfect like a Mozart piano sonata. The only issue for me to testing it is that I am not so expert of the cli and I wrote the app in php, so I check for files with `scandir()` and execute ImageMagick commands with `exec("convert ... ")`. Question is: can I add the whole conditional structure into the exec command in php?

Comment: Sure, you can do `exec("convert inputFile -regard-warnings ... processed/outputFile.jpg && rm inputFile");`

Comment: Or you can add an `output_array` and `return_var` to your `exec` and then test the `return_var` and remove the file if it is zero - i.e. if the command worked... http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Comment: I have tried twice, with `-reset-warnings` after `convert` then after  `camera_roll/SUBSONICA.JPG` Exec: `exec("convert -size 1280x44.879451 xc:none -gravity center -pointsize 24 -font 'Times-Bold' -stroke black -strokewidth 1 -annotate 0 '©M.Setchell' -background none -shadow 100x3+0+0 +repage -stroke none -fill white -annotate 0 '©M.Setchell' roll/SUBSONICA.JPG  -regard-warnings +swap -gravity south -geometry +0-3 -composite send/SUBSONICA.JPG && rm roll/SUBSONICA.JPG");` while uploading manually images. Got mail with 8 images, 4 partial, but processed. Is there something wrong in the exec?

Comment: Oh my! I can't read that in the `comment` area. Please click `edit` under your original question and paste it in formatted properly and I'll check it out.

Comment: Ok, I have got it in PHP format now. The problem was that `convert` was creating a partial output file even if the input file was incomplete. I have now changed it so that if it works, the input file is deleted, and if it doesn't work, the (partial) output file is deleted. See updated answer above - sorry I was only half-correct at my first attempt :-)

Comment: It worked just perfectly. I just updated the question in order to show the code snippets and give a little detail. (FYI, now the php function in the class has your name :-) ).